# Why Jupyter console sometimes decide to output sometimes don't?

Tags: python, elpy, ipython, jupyter

## Problem

---

I don't know why my Jupyter console sometimes doesn't output anything. An example is this:
[image: Problem]
Notice that only the first line gets its output. I use C-enter to execute each line. Line 2, 3, 4, 5 are just "silent". Especially line 5, shouldn't it be the same as line 1?

## Setup

---

Here is my elpy config screen:
[image: elpy config]

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: @Drew Thank you for removing the tag. I do not know this.

Comment: No problem. You're welcome. Welcome to the site.